# grabbing google calendar events and parsing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

We are using google calendar for on call schedules.

We would like to scrape the calendar for specific events and parse the information.

This information will be used in a script for routing email and phone notification.

If any of this sounds like a familiar project or example, I would appreciate a point in that direction.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Apps Script exposes calendars using the [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendar) and [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarapp) class. Write the script in a Google spreadsheet and then add a time driven trigger to run it every hour/day/month/whatever. Just click *Resources > Current script's triggers* in the script editor.

You can also get an XML feed using the url: `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/username%40gmail.com/public/basic` and then parse that. [ Discontinued 11/2015: https://www.404techsupport.com/2015/10/google-discontinue-feed-google-calendars/ ]